# Remove all base64 occurrences from a collection's array in MongoDB using $regex

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with an images object that contains an array of base64 images and normal file names. I need to remove all base64 elements and keep only the file names.

```
 images: {
      more:[
       'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Q...',
       'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Q...',
       'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Q...',
       'file1.png', 
       'file2.png'
      ]
  }
```

I used these queries but i cannot update the array:

```
  db.cars.updateMany({}, {$pull: {'images.more': {$regex: '/^data(.+)$/'}}})

  db.cars.updateMany({}, {$pull: {'images.more': {$regex: '/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/'}}})
```

Both queries return:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 163, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

In example object i use image/jpeg but it might also contain bmp images or png so regex must match all possible image types.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the `/` delimiters in the `$regex` string value:

```
db.cars.updateMany({}, {$pull: {'images.more': {$regex: '^data(.+)$'}}})
```

The `/` delimiters are only used for the JS regex syntax (which also works):

```
db.cars.updateMany({}, {$pull: {'images.more': {$regex: /^data(.+)$/}}})
```